# Using join or duplicating when shared column is small?

Tags: mysql, join

I am looking for a best practice for multiple tables in a vertical hierarchy having small shared data. Let's say three tables:

```
Country {
   id 
}

State {
   id,
   country_id,
   FK_to_country_id,
}

City {
   id,
   state_id,
   FK_to_state_id,
}
```

in above state belongs to country while city belongs to state and turns out to belong to country as well. The schema looks clean but when you want to look up which country a city belongs to, you have to use a JOIN with three tables. If there is another tier called County which belongs to city, the situation gets worse.

```
City {
   id,
   country_id,
   state_id,
   FK_to_country_id,
   FK_to_state_id,
}
```

adding another column 'country_id' in City frees us from cumbersome JOIN but the database schema gets a little duplicate.

What's practice in real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `JOIN`s are made for; don't deprive them of their duty.

In real-world practice, it is absolutely normal to be joining multiple tables like that.

In your example, yes it would be redundant to have country ID's in the city table.

But it's not always the case.  Consider an example where a city can exist without needing to be in a state (a lot of 3rd-world countries have no "state" designation), then you have to have that foreign-key country ID, because the `State` table is optional.

Comment: Will JOIN clause be too complicated if the hierarchy is rather deep such like 5, 6 levels? I want to know if such sort of redundancy works as a tradeoff in real practice?

Comment: 6-6 levels is already too complicated, at which point the `JOIN` actually simplifies if you think about it.  Don't be surprised to see 7 `JOIN`s in a row for such a thing.  Then again, it all depends on your schema and what your data represents.